# codeml from BioPython never finish

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, python-3.5

I'm trying to use BioPython to run PAML and run these code:

```
from Bio.Phylo.PAML import codeml
cml = codeml.Codeml(alignment = "lysin.phy", tree = "lysin.trees", out_file = "results.out")
cml.read_ctl_file("codeml.ctl")
results=cml.run()
```

However, cml.run() will go to sleep and never finish. When I cancel it, the message return is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/bioinfo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/biopython-1.66-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/Bio/Phylo/PAML/codeml.py", line 186, in run
Paml.run(self, ctl_file, verbose, command)
File "/home/bioinfo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/biopython-1.66-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/Bio/Phylo/PAML/_paml.py", line 145, in run
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/home/bioinfo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 562, in call
return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
File "/home/bioinfo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1651, in wait
(pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
File "/home/bioinfo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1601, in _try_wait
(pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Can anyone help me to figure out where is the error. The alignment file and tree file I used are in PAML example folder.

Comment: Which version of PAML do you have, and can does it run properly outside Biopython? i.e. Is it installed properly. Also which OS are you using? I can tell you're using Python 3.5 from Anaconda from the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following tweak worked. I dont know why and don't have time to figure out right now, but will be glad if someone can explain. Basically, the order was important, otherwise the parameters are set back to null [you can verify it by cml.print_options()].

```
cml = codeml.Codeml()
cml.read_ctl_file("ctl_file_path")
cml.tree = "full_tree_path"
cml.alignment = "full_alignment_path"
cml.out_file = "full_out_path"
cml.working_dir = "full_dir_path"

cml.run()
```

It did not work when:

1. ctl file was read after setting other options
2. options were set using the constructor codeml.Codeml()
3. working_dir was not set (despite giving full paths to all files)

I was also running python through conda.